# Why does this Dataflow pipeline run with no errors, but doesn't read any data?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm running a streaming Dataflow pipeline from MongoDB to BigQuery. This is the code I'm using:

```
beam_options = PipelineOptions(
    beam_args,
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project=my_project,
    job_name=my_job_name,
    temp_location=my_temp_location,
    region=my_region,
    streaming=True,
    subnetwork=my_network,
    service_account_email=my_sa)


with Pipeline(options=beam_options) as p:
    input = p | "Read from MongoDB" >> ReadFromMongoDB(uri=c_string, db=my_db, coll=my_coll, filter=my_filter,  bucket_auto=True)
    input | "Write to BigQuery" >> WriteToBigQuery(table=my_table, dataset=my_dataset, project=my_project, method='STREAMING_INSERTS')
```

The pipeline starts smoothly and doesn't show any errors in the job page. However, it doesn't read any data or create any workers. The number of workers and CPU processed remains 0.

On looking at the GCE logs, I can see the following error:

```
The resource 'projects/my_project/global/instanceTemplates/my_instance_template' already exists
```

It is repeated every minute, and I've also seen a code error 13 in similar logs. I'm not sure what's going on, but it seems Dataflow is having issues spinning up the necessary infrastructure for the job to run.

Any idea on what could be causing this behaviour?

NB: I have omitted all the PII due to privacy concerns.

Comment: It's hard to say, but it looks like it's having trouble spinning up Dataflow workers since the worker count stays at 0. But it's strange that it's trying to create duplicate instance templates, unless there's something in the code you didn't include that involves creating instance templates. It might be a good idea to contact Cloud Support.

Comment: @Hyperion did you have any luck finding an answer?

Comment: @BrianBien no, I changed my approach and used Fivetran instead of Dataflow. It's working like a charm so far.

Answer (score 1):

A vague answer, but it might help others who had the same issue: I believe the underlying issue was related to the job template having a different region than the region being set at runtime to run the job.